# 1366 Incorrect decimal value Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have driver model with this condition :

```
protected $fillable = [
'hourly_rate',
'ot_hourly_rate',
'commission_rate',
'basic_salary',
'join_date',
];
```

and here's my migration code :

```
public function up()
{
Schema::table('drivers', function ($table) {
    $table->integer('hourly_rate', 24,2)->nullable()->default(0);
    $table->decimal('ot_hourly_rate', 24,2)->nullable()->default(0);
    $table->decimal('commission_rate', 24,2)->nullable()->default(0);
    $table->decimal('basic_salary', 24,2)->nullable()->default(0);
});
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{   
Schema::table('drivers', function ($table) {
    $table->dropColumn('hourly_rate');
    $table->dropColumn('ot_hourly_rate');
    $table->dropColumn('commission_rate');
    $table->dropColumn('basic_salary');
});
}
```

the problem is when I try to create driver and didn't fill those field it says error decimal value. decimal can't store empty string as NULL at database ?

note : those field is not required.

Comment: why do you have nullable and default? Do you want it to be default to 0 or null when new row is added? Try adding `default('0')` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

No need to set nullable because you set default value .Try this

```
 $table->decimal('basic_salary', 24,2)->default(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Available Column Types](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#creating-columns)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('drivers', function ($table) {
        $table->integer('hourly_rate')->default(0);
        $table->decimal('ot_hourly_rate', 24,2)->default(0);
        $table->decimal('commission_rate', 24,2)->default(0);
        $table->decimal('basic_salary', 24,2)->default(0);
    });
}

public function down()
{   
    Schema::drop('drivers');
}
```

Declaration: `decimal(p[,s]).`

p = Precision - total number of digits stored to both the left and right of the decimal point.

s = Scale the maximum number of digits stored to the right of the decimal point (optional).

Minimum Precision is 1 and Maximum Precision is 38. The Default Precision is 18.

> Note: Decimal is equivalent to Numeric.

[more details](http://www.tsqltutorials.com/datatypes.php)

Comment: I have the same problem and setting it to default value 0 doesn't work :(

Comment: same issue, and as @lewis4u said, this doesn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue recently, and the complication was with my input fields.

Submitting this
`<input name="ex" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="0.00">`
would make the input field equal to "". Regardless of the defaults in your migration you'll still run into an error because the default 
"" is not a proper decimal.

I chose to simply change my input fields to be more like this,
`<input name="ex" type="number" step="0.01" value="0" required>` That way the default is 0 rather than "", and the required field prevents the submission if the default value is removed and not replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the empty values to null by traversing through the inputs.

Ex by doing:

```
    array_walk_recursive(
        $params,
        function (&$value) {
            if ( $value == "" ) {
                $value = null;
            }
        }
    );
```